# Corona SDK error on lines 172 and 218, no filename, only question marks

Tags: error-handling, lua, runtime-error, coronasdk

Corona SDK simulator, version 2013.1137 (2013.6.7) is displaying the following error:

```
Corona Simulator Runtime error

File: ?

Attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a function value)

stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    ?: in function <?:172>
    ?: in function <?:218>
```

The error is caused by the following code (**main.lua**):

```
local d1 = display.newCircle(0, 40, 10)
local gNonEmpty1 = display.newGroup()
gNonEmpty1:insert(display.newCircle(0, 70, 10))
local gEmpty1 = display.newGroup()

transition.to(d1, { time = 1000, x = 100 })
transition.to(gNonEmpty1, { time = 1000, x = 100 })
transition.to(gEmpty1, { time = 1000, x = 100 })

local d2 = display.newCircle(0, 150, 10)
local gNonEmpty2 = display.newGroup()
gNonEmpty2:insert(display.newCircle(0, 180, 10))
local gEmpty2 = display.newGroup()

transition.to(d2, { time = 1000, x = 100, transition = easing.outExpo })
transition.to(gNonEmpty2, { time = 1000, x = 100, transition = easing.outExpo })
transition.to(gEmpty2, { time = 1000, x = 100, transition = easing.outExpo })

local d3 = display.newCircle(0, 260, 10)
local gNonEmpty3 = display.newGroup()
gNonEmpty3:insert(display.newCircle(0, 290, 10))
local gEmpty3 = display.newGroup()

transition.to(d3, { time = 1000, x = 100, easing.outExpo })
transition.to(gNonEmpty3, { time = 1000, x = 100, easing.outExpo })
transition.to(gEmpty3, { time = 1000, x = 100, easing.outExpo })
```

The actual line causing the error is the second to last one:

```
transition.to(gNonEmpty3, { time = 1000, x = 100, easing.outExpo })
```

You can check it out by commenting it.

Corona documentation states that:

```
You should have at least one DisplayObject inserted into a
Display Group before you change or read any of the properties
of the group (e.g., x, y, setReferencePoint(), etc.).
```

Hence, it would be legit to expect some weird behavior when using **transition.to**
on **gEmpty1**, **gEmpty2** or **gEmpty3**. As expected, the first two blocks of **transition.to**, for a total of six calls, behave the same, except for the easing
which is the default, **easing.linear**, for the first three calls, and **easing.outExpo** for the other three calls.

If you make a mistake in writing the **transition.to** calls, and you write something similar to the last three **transition.to** calls, where the **transition =** part is missing in the specification of the easing function, the surprising thing is that only the one that targets the *non-empty* group, **gNonEmpty3** is responsible for the incomprehensible error message.

**Questions**

1. What should you do in Corona SDK when you get an error with no line numbers and no file names, but only question marks?
2. Why Corona SDK is not able to provide meaningful reporting beside two line numbers, 172 and 218?
3. Why this error is occurring? My theory is that the **transition.to** doesn't perform much error checking; if you target an empty group the error in specifying the easing function will go unnoticed; probably this is related with the fact empty groups properties should not be used, so maybe **transition.to** *or* its internal update callback finds out that the group is empty and simply returns without doing anything. Instead, for the non-empty group, the missing **transition =** causes some code to be triggered **not necessarily the easing code**, and in that code the actual error occurs.

**config.lua**

```
application = {
    content = {
        width = 320,
        height = 480, 
        scale = "letterBox",
        fps = 30
    } 
}
```

**Original Post (obsolete)**

I'm having a hard time at tracking down an error in Corona SDK.
The error causes the simulator to show the following message:

```
Corona Simulator Runtime error

File: ?

Attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a function value)

stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    ?: in function <?:172>
    ?: in function <?:218>
```

**How shall I interpret such message?** I have no source files with
that many lines, by the way.

I have a file named Button.lua and line 41 seems to be involved
in raising an exception, although it is not raised from that
line. The line is:

```
button:insert(b1)
```

I wrapped that line between two prints:

```
print("Before", button, b1) 
button:insert(b1)
print("After")
```

The following messages are printed in the simulator console:

```
Corona Simulator[9801:f03] Before    table: 0x11daf4aa0    table: 0x1152363a0
Corona Simulator[9801:f03] After
```

Comment: I think that the information that you provided is not enough for us to help you out. Almost everything in Lua is represented as a table so your print is not necessary. Simply try to insert some more prints to trace down at what point the runtime error occur. Though, it sounds like you are trying to use a function in some arithmetics or you might have used a variable name that is already occupied by something else.

Comment: Hi Pontus thank you for your comment. I have more print statements in my code but I still haven't been able to detect when the program stops working. I think this is happening because of the use of **transition.to** and **onComplete** callbacks. Probably things are screwing up in an asynchronous callback and I can't understand which one exactly. I guess I'll keep adding more prints but I have literally no clue where to start from.

Comment: As @Pontus suggested: post more code. You really gave little context for us to analyze the problem. You probably have a function stored in a wrong place that belongs to a number.

Comment: Is `button` a `GroupObject` or `DisplayObject`?
[Documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/GroupObject/insert.html) is kind a shady in this case, so, not sure if You can `insert` a `DisplayObject` into another `DisplayObject`.

Comment: @damix911: This is a common problem in LUA due to syntax/logic error. Pls provide us sufficient information about: `button`, `b1` and the function/callback you mentioned. Check the availability of objects inside your function (or declare them as: local objectName) in the top of your page.

Comment: @everybody: thank you for your help, I'll post soon a self contained example and sorry that I wasn't able to provide more information sooner. The problem is indeed related with the interaction between display and group objects. Basically, I have an error in a **transition.to** call that targets a group object (I forgot "transition =" before the easing function); when I insert something into this group, that error causes an exception. The wrong code was there since the very early stages of development and went completely unnoticed for days.

Comment: @Kamiccolo thank you for your observation, **button** is a GroupObject but check the above comment because you were on the right track. The documentation states that *You should have at least one DisplayObject inserted into a Display Group before you change or read any of the properties of the group (e.g., x, y, setReferencePoint(), etc.).* Ironically, while leaving **button** empty is in a way an error in Corona, it probably counter the error in **transition.to**. In operational terms, **transition.to** sees that something is wrong with **button** and the easing function code doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your line:

```
transition.to(gNonEmpty3, { time = 1000, x = 100, easing.outExpo })
```

use :

```
transition.to(gNonEmpty3, { time = 1000, x = 100, transition =  easing.outExpo })
```

---

In corona, such error message will occur when you have some `wrong syntax` or `wrong logic`. So, check for those issues first. Inserting `print` between the lines (that you used) is the best solution to find such error lines.

Keep Coding............. :)

Comment: Thank you. I realize I didn't write it very clearly, but I knew where the error in the code was; my question is more like: why can't Corona provide a decent report? In my project I spotted the missing **transition =** by pure chance. What should I do when confronted with such an obscure error message?